# Change color of WKInterfacePicker on WatchKit 2.0

Tags: ios, uipickerview, watchkit

Is there any possibility to change the color of a Picker with Outline? At the moment it is green. But this doesn't match with the other colors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set WKInterfacePicker color (text or outline)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923649/set-wkinterfacepicker-color-text-or-outline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to change it, but remember that Xcode (7.0 beta 4) and WatchKit 0S 2 are in beta version.

Comment: There still doesn't seem to be a way to change the colour (Xcode 8.2.1, watchOS 3.1.3)